# Sharp angles causing problems when baking normals

Tags: texture-baking, normals, baking, normal-map

I'm trying to bake normals from a high to a low poly in blender, but I keep getting these faulty areas along creases and sharp angels. I can decrease the ray distance and /or extrusion, but then the rays won't reach other parts of the blade anymore.

Does anyone know how to fix this or what the proper workflow is here?

The low poly is a contiguous mesh. The high poly is a single object containing multiple intersecting meshes. I've tried turning my high poly in a contiguous mesh as well, but it made no difference. I was only able to make the problem less apparent by adding loop cuts close to these problematic areas, but that doesn't seem like a proper solution to me.

[image]

After adding a loop cut, the problem is contained within these smaller faces.

[image]

Comment: That effect is caused by the normal map's resolution. Normal maps are pixel graphics and those pixels are shown more prominently the smaller your normal map's resolution is. The only way to "fix" it *to some extend* is to bake your normal map in a higher resolution. If your model is a game asset, big resolutions might be counterproductive.

Comment: I doubled the resolution a few times, but it has no effect. I think the extrusion is causing the rays to hit the back of the opposite faces where the faces get to close to eachother. I just have no idea how to fix that without creating blank areas in other parts of the UV.